# jquery rows height dynamic resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a jquery plugin for column dynamic resizing - colResizable: http://quocity.com/colresizable/.

Is there any similar plugin for row height dynamic resizing?

[image: Example]

Comment: please be more specific...  have you tried using "%" widths? Provide some sample html along with more spefific requirements

Comment: DO you want all row heights to be the same based on the largest one? Or automatically get larger with content (which they shoudl do naturally)?

Comment: I just want to implement the same behavior as it is implemented in colResizable plugin. Where width of each table column can be dynamically changed using drag&drop. I need to to change height of the row instead of width of the column.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps [Jquery UI Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) could make that happen for you.  I've never used it for that, but it seems like it would work.

You could also do it at the cell level as well.

Comment: as i know ui resizable does not work with table elements (especially in Firefox)